# Android App Reject due to noncompliant version(s) of SDK: Tencent TBS

Tags: android, flutter, release, google-play-console

I have developed my flutter app using Flutter 3.7.5. I am facing this issue when I release android application.

```
Issue found: Violation of Device and Network Abuse policy
We reviewed SDKs used by your app and found noncompliant version(s) of SDK(s) which contains code to download executable code (for example, dex, JAR, .so files) from a source other than Google Play.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Version code 14:
SDK: Tencent TBS
To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:

You may consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK, if available from your SDK provider or removing the SDK.
```

I checked available solution for this issue, where they suggested to migrate [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin. Which I did. But still facing same issue. Need your help to solve this issue, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, [Webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin contains `Tencent TBS SDK`, Either you can change that package or update proper permission related to requirements.

To check plug-ins of your app, you have to global search in your project in Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

You should update or remove 'Tencent TBS'